# Ошибка (argument of type "const wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter of type "WCHAR*) - DirectX 11

Tags: directx

Кто сможет подсказать в чем дело, выполняю пример с сайта Rastertek.com. Добрался до оформления класса работающего с шейдерами:
[Tutorial 4: Buffers, Shaders, and HLSL](https://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut04.html)

Ок, зер гуд, но в секции:

```
 bool ColorShaderClass::Initialize(ID3D11Device* device, HWND hwnd)
{
 bool result;
 // Initialize the vertex and pixel shaders.
 result = InitializeShader(device, hwnd, L"../Engine/color.vs", L"../Engine/color.ps");
if(!result)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

начинается эпическая ересь с подчеркиванием литеры L в строке:

```
result = InitializeShader(device, hwnd, L"../Engine/color.vs", L"../Engine/color.ps");
```

и выводом ошибки: 
argument of type "const wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter of type "WCHAR*
Причем если скачать файлы с сайта-данная ошибка отсутствует.
В настройках к проекту, в разделе Advanced->Charcter Set уже выставлено Use Unicode Character Set. И по идее, ошибки не должно быть.
Возможно, ошибка возникает из-за того что использовал при создании проекта Windows Desctop Wizard где были применены предварительные настройки не подходящие для работы с DirectX.

Comment: Измените сигнатуру InitializeShader чтобы она принимала `wchar_t const *`. Ну и вообще соблюдайте const correctness.

Comment: спасибо, действительно) почему автор сайта не заметил данную проблему неясно)